# Hide item from array

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am showing the product categories on the WooCommerce thank you page using this piece of code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'show_product_category', 10, 1 );
function show_product_category ( $order_id ){
    // Get $product object from $order / $order_id
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();

        print_r ($product->get_categories());

    }
}
```

The code above shows all categories, but I need to hide a specific category. Is it possible to hide a specific category by ID in the above code?

Comment: What does `print_r ($product->get_categories());` show? Which category do you want to skip?

Comment: print_r is only a debug tool, you should not use that to present actual content to the frontend user in the first place. And once you _loop over_ the array of options you got there, to create some sort of proper structured output, it is easy to put a little `if` into that loop, that simply skips the current item if its ID is the one you don't want to see ...

Comment: I will remove the print_r on the production website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woocommerce uses main get_categories() function from Wordpress core.

You can exclude any categories with passing option arguments to function based on "[WP Terms Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/)"

**exclude** parameter should be array or comma/space-separated string of category IDs to exclude.

```
$categories = $product->get_categories(array(
    'exclude' => array( 10, 11 ) // change these IDs
));
```